# Как создать jar файл в idea?

Tags: java, javafx

У меня имеется немаленькое javafx приложение, но при создании jar файла он не запускается. Очень жаль, ведь на проект потратил 3 месяца

Я уже попробовал такую инструкцию:

1. Project Settings, вкладка Artifacts. Нажимаем [+], в выпавшем меню выбираем JAR.
2. В панели слева - содержимое JAR-файла, в панели справа - содержимое проекта. Перетаскиваем справа налево все, что хотим включить в JAR.
3. Указываем имя для файла и директорию назначения над панелями
4. Нажимаем на кнопку create manifest под левой панелью, создаем manifest.mf. При этом IDE спросит Main class и classpath для указания в манифесте.
5. Не забудем поставить галочку "Build on make" над панелями
6. Теперь в меню Build есть команда сборки артефакта

Но после этого всего jar файл все равно не запускался. В среде разработки все отлично работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пробовали запустить через терминал? Если да то какую ошибку выдавал?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать сборщики проектов ( ant, maven). Это займет немного времени на обучение, но это пригодится в будущем

Comment: Можете скинуть видео или статью по этому поводу(ant, maven)?

Comment: попробуй открыть jar-файл, и там найти манифест, при генерации jar-ки, там может пропадать Main-Class. Если его нет, то допиши и обнови архив

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть много. Например, проблема может быть с файлом `Manifest`, с указанием местположении `fxml` (у меня IDEA предлагала указывать корневую папку с помощью `../`, что является не правильным определением пути), с добавлением сторонних библиотек и т.д.

Для того чтобы отловить надо запустить через `jar` файл. Вы можете в важей же среде разработки запустить `jar` файл. Там в консоли будут отображены все ошибки. Так же, можно запустить с терминала. В папке с файлом надо прописать:

`java -jar [имя_файла].jar`